# display fusion table map in android app

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm working with android studios and I'm trying to display a fusion table map in my android app. In javascript, it's straightforward by using the "FusionTablesLayer" function from the GoogleMaps object. Is there anything similar in java such that I can add a fusion tables layer in my google maps within my android app?

In short (taking the example from google docs), I'm trying to do the same as the below javascript but in java in my android app:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 41.850033, lng: -87.6500523},
    zoom: 11
  });

  var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: '\'Geocodable address\'',
      from: '1mZ53Z70NsChnBMm-qEYmSDOvLXgrreLTkQUvvg'
    }
  });
  layer.setMap(map);
}
```

Thank you
T.